# Node/Express route showing incorrect output

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am new to Node/Express and in the early stages of writing a restful API where the developer can access the "/zwave/devices" path with an HTTP GET to receive a list of devices in JSON format.

I am able to obtain the raw device JSON via an XHR request from another source and output it to the console successfully for debugging purposes when starting the app, however, when I access "/zwave/devices" through a browser the JSON output shown in the console is an empty object {}.

When starting the app, I get back the full JSON data I'm expecting **in the console**.  However, when I visit /zwave/devices after waiting for zwave.getDevicesJSON() to finish, I don't.  Why?

Thanks in advance for the help.

**server.js**

```
// Singleton; shared state and behavior of a single class instance.
var zwave = require('./zwave.js');

// Route for /zwave/devices that should send JSON output to console for debugging.
app.get('/zwave/devices', function(req, res) {
  zwave.showDevicesJSON();         // Displays second, incorrectly; outputs {}
  console.log(zwave.devicesJSON);  // Displays third, incorrectly; outputs {}
});

var server = app.listen(http_port, function () {    
  // Initial get of device JSON data, with a callback to show JSON in the console
  zwave.getDevicesJSON(zwave.showDevicesJSON);  // Displays first, correctly; outputs JSON
});
```

**zwave.js**

```
function Zwave() {
  this.devicesJSON = {};    
};

Zwave.prototype.getDevicesJSON = function(callback) {  
  // Working XHR code here to obtain device JSON.
  this.devicesJSON = JSON.parse(data); 
  callback.bind(this)();
};

Zwave.prototype.showDevicesJSON = function(req,res) {  
  console.log('Show Devices Is Firing');
  console.log(this.devicesJSON);      
};

module.exports = new Zwave();
```

Comment: *JSON.parse(data)* ! what is *data* you are parsing.

Comment: Did you create a route with app.use("/pathURI", require("./realPathToYourRouteFile")); ?

Answer (score 0):

Is because  you never send an output as response

try putting this

```
app.get('/zwave/devices', function(req, res) {
   zwave.showDevicesJSON();         // Displays second, incorrectly; outputs {}
   console.log(zwave.devicesJSON);  // Displays third, incorrectly; outputs {}
 res.json(zwave.devicesJSON);
});
```

you can lean more about routing here

http://expressjs.com/starter/basic-routing.html

Comment: Thank you for commenting, however this is not the answer I need. Even with the res.json(zwave.devicesJSON), which does send the response, the output is still {}